# Div to be fixed at the top of the window

Tags: javascript, css, html, position

Guys I want to fix a div width and height as 100%. But the problem is that div is inside a  wrapper with a fixed width.

I have a button above the div which onclick="" makes the div to change its class with full width and height. i want to position that div to the top-left corner of the window.My code is

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Javascript Change CSS Class of Div tag</title>

    <style type="text/css">

    #wrapper
    {
        width:75%;
        height:75%;
        margin:0 auto;
    }
    .minimize {
        color : red;
        width:500px;
        height:200px;
        background:#474747;
        float:left;
     } 

     .maximize {
        color : blue;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        float:left;
        background:#ccc;
     }

    </style>

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

        function changeCssClass(navlink)
        {
            if(document.getElementById(navlink).className=='minimize')
            {
                document.getElementById(navlink).className = 'maximize';
            }
            else
            {
                document.getElementById(navlink).className = 'minimize';
            }
        }

    </script>

</head>
<body>   <div id="wrapper">
        <div  id="navlink" class="minimize"><input type="button" value="click here" onclick="changeCssClass('navlink')" /> </div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

But i want to make it to look like this with wrapper

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Javascript Change CSS Class of Div tag</title>

    <style type="text/css">


    .minimize {
        color : red;
        width:500px;
        height:200px;
        background:#474747;
        float:left;
     } 

     .maximize {
        color : blue;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        float:left;
        background:#ccc;
     }



</style>

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

        function changeCssClass(navlink)
        {
            if(document.getElementById(navlink).className=='minimize')
            {
                document.getElementById(navlink).className = 'maximize';
            }
            else
            {
                document.getElementById(navlink).className = 'minimize';
            }
        }

    </script>

</head>
<body>   
        <div  id="navlink" class="minimize"><input type="button" value="click here" onclick="changeCssClass('navlink')" /> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Will any one help here....

If anyone has any suggestion??

Comment: why dont you use jQuery it would be far more easier to do this.. look at this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/gqNsA/5/

Comment: Thats good its working Berker i will use this if its not possible by simple javascript.Thanks for this nice suggestion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is what you were after, but it was hard to tell because you didn't specify exactly what states should be held for .minimize and .maximize.

Notice that the javascript is substantially different than your original.

Since 'class' is an attribute on DOM elements, it should be accessed using getAttribute and setAttribute. There was a very, very old bug in IE6 that would only let javascript access an element's classes via className, but that is no longer the case.

Additionally, take notice of how I'm handling the class attribute. Since you can specify multiple classes on an element, this code takes that into account. You can safely add more classes without fidgeting with maximize and minimize.

The 2nd thing to look at is the css. Using position:fixed will lock the element into position no matter what the scroll value is. In this example, there are 2 ways to set the div to be full screen. The first is specifying width and height at 100%. However, this is brittle.

Its better to set top, right, bottom, and left to 0. This gives you more control. Also, suppose you wanted a thin margin around the edges. Instead of worrying about mixing top and left with width and height, you can just specify a pixel or percentage value for the 4 properties I've mentioned to get an easy, uniform look.

Answer (score 3):

I checked Berker's [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gqNsA/5/) and it will fix your problem.
Sowmya uses this fiddle, but I have made a few changes, check this out:

Since `class` is an attribute on DOM elements, it should be accessed using `getAttribute` and `setAttribute`. There was a very, very old bug in IE6 that would only let javascript access an element's classes via `className`, but that is no longer the case.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/Tv2pP/7/

I think this is what you were after, but it was hard to tell because you didn't specify exactly what states should be held for .minimize and .maximize.

Notice that the javascript is substantially different than your original.

Since 'class' is an attribute on DOM elements, it should be accessed using getAttribute and setAttribute. There was a very, very old bug in IE6 that would only let javascript access an element's classes via className, but that is no longer the case.

Additionally, take notice of how I'm handling the class attribute. Since you can specify multiple classes on an element, this code takes that into account. You can safely add more classes without fidgeting with maximize and minimize.

The 2nd thing to look at is the css. Using position:fixed will lock the element into position no matter what the scroll value is. In this example, there are 2 ways to set the div to be full screen. The first is specifying width and height at 100%. However, this is brittle.

Its better to set top, right, bottom, and left to 0. This gives you more control. Also, suppose you wanted a thin margin around the edges. Instead of worrying about mixing top and left with width and height, you can just specify a pixel or percentage value for the 4 properties I've mentioned to get an easy, uniform look.

Lastly, if you have the option you should use a standardized library like jQuery. It has become an incredibly useful tool over the years for doing exactly this kind of thing without you, the developer, having to worry about the underlying browser platform discrepancies too much.

Comment: I tried this fiddle dude. Could you point out where i am making mistake in this `<style>
#wrapper
 {
  width:75%;
  height:75%;
  margin:0 100px;
  background:#ccc;
 }
    .minimize {
        color : red;
  width:500px;
  height:200px;
  background:#474747;
  float:left;
  
     } 
     
     .maximize {
        color : blue;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  float:left;
  background:#ccc;
  
     }
</style>`

Comment: Script i used the same one as in fiddle.   **HTML** `<div id="wrapper">
  <div  id="navlink" class="minimize"><input type="button" value="click here" onclick="changeCssClass('navlink')"  id="btn"/> </div>
        </div>`

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Look at the fiddle I provided and read the css and javascript. Its fairly self-explanatory.

Comment: there is no css in that fiddle just javascript. When i apply those in my code button is not working

Comment: The css is in the same place you put it, in the html section.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `margin:0` auto from the wrapper class

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/PAj39/

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/Tv2pP/7/

I think this is what you were after, but it was hard to tell because you didn't specify exactly what states should be held for .minimize and .maximize.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `margin:0 auto` from the wrapper class

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/PAj39/

---

The below method makes the inner div to align top left to the browser

add `position:fixed; top:0; left:0` to `.minimize`

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/PAj39/2/

Comment: I have some more content in them i just want to make that specific div to be position on the top-left which must hide other contents and be displayed on full screen.

Comment: so you need wrapper to be center aligned and inner div to be left top aligned?

Comment: Its works thanks for that suggestion. Instead of adding position:fixed; top:0; left:0 to .minimize i changed it to .maximize thats the output i really wanted :). Thanks

Comment: .maximize div doesn't exist in you html code given so i changed it to minimize.

Comment: I have an issue is there a way to fix the wrapper in middle with margin:0 auto?

Comment: presently it is in the middle right? with margin:0 auto... then whats the problem

Comment: oh its visible to me. I uploaded my entire coding. May be some error But its ok i got your point

Comment: Hmmm yes but its fixed to left corner in IE.

Comment: demo fiddle is tested in all the versions of IE. U can cross check the demo. If it is not working with your entire code then there might be clash between your other class

Comment: that is because you dont have switching div in the code (maximize div is not there in html code)

Comment: maximize is not a div its just a class. the style of the div navlink is changed from minimize class to maximize class

Comment: Look at my answer. Its solved the various coding issues that existed in the original sample.

Comment: I used that fiddle just having some issuses that the button is not working @Geuis

Answer (score 0):

Just set the div width:100%; with position:fixed; to it.

But the wrapper must have position:absolute; property